# C# check data in json file

Tags: c#, json

I'm writing a plugin for a game server modification.
Basically the plugin revokes the item dropping right from players if they don't have the bypass permission.

This worked but when a player removes an already placed object from the world, the plugin shows the error message and gets in a loop giving the player the same item said player removed. ( I guess it need a break; but I'm not sure)

I tried to extend the plugin by adding excluded items. The plugin would check if the item ID the player tries to drop is listed in a .json config file. If it is, then said player drops the item. If not listed, then the item gets deleted, except if the player has the bypass permission.
The difficulty I'm have is that I don't know how to check the item IDs listed in the .json file.
Another alternative is to leave the .json file and put the allowed item IDs inside the code, but I have no idea how to do this either.

I know this is very basic and easy, but  just started with c#. I'm reading one of my teacher's book  about basic C#, but I would like to finish this project soon.

http://pastebin.com/RgBmtus9

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to include an example of the JSON you want to read.

Comment: Also, rather than linking to a large file, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of what you want to accomplish.  If you do, it is more likely we will be able to help.

Comment: Sorry about the file, I copy pasted the code into a pastebin. I can assure you it is not a homework. We only learned c++ 2 years ago. The most complicated program we learned to make was a chess game. This is for personal use. (

Comment: You are already serializing and deserializing a class `Config`.  Do you just need to check [`if config.Exclusions != null && config.Exclusions.Contains(dropId)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

The linked code fragment doesn't seem to be complete or to compile standalone.  Reading through, your code to serialize and deserialize your `Config` class looks valid, though I can't actually compile and test your `DropBan` class.

So, is this what you want?

```
public class DropBan : TerrariaPlugin
{  
    private Config config;

    bool IsExcluded(int id)
    {
        if (config == null)
        {
            ReadConfig();
        }
        return config != null && config.Exclusions != null && config.Exclusions.Contains(id);
    }

    public class Config
    {
        public int[] Exclusions = { 267, 188 };
    }

    // Rest as as shown at http://pastebin.com/RgBmtus9
}
```

Comment: Yes this will be the solution, but it still won't let the player drop the excluded item.